# Magento 2 upload logo from admin in svg format

Tags: magento2

In **Magento 2.2.2** , I want to upload header **logo** of **svg** format from admin panel. I have created a module for it

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="other_settings">
    <fieldset name="head">
        <field name="head_shortcut_icon">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg ico</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

After that run the upgrade, deploy and cache clean command and then again upload the svg format logo from admin then it showing the message "Disallowed file type".

So please help me

Comment: I am also facing the same problem..How did you upload SVG logo in backend?Kindly share your thoughts